# Flex smooth progress bar with percentage

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar

I want to make a loading indicator that shows the exact progress with percentage (something like bootstrap's [*progress bar*](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress)), instead of just an endlessly spinning wheel (which actually doesn't give any information to the user if anything is happening or just the spinning wheel is broken).

Is there something like this in Flex or I have to implement my own?

Also the other problem is that I don't know for what time I will get my information (which updates the progress bar) and the loading will look very segmented. Is there a way to do this in a smoother way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar component, you can make it using [ProgressBar control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d8c.html).

Comment: I was looking for the manual mode of the progress bar, thanks. Didn't know that there is such mode.